# Why am I getting a "RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded" error?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, passwords, mongoose

I have my website hosted by Node.js with html and when I POST from a form below:

```
 <form class="validateForm" id="registerform" method="POST" action="/signUp"  accept-charset='UTF-8'>
            <fieldset>
                <legend>Register</legend> <br>
                <input type="text" name="firstName" id="firstName" placeholder="First Name" maxlength="20" value=""/> <br>
                <input type="text" name="lastName" id="lastName" placeholder="Last Name" maxlength="20" value=""/> <br>
                <input type="text" name="email" id="email" placeholder="Email" maxlength="30" value=""/> <br>
                <input type="password" name="password" id="password" placeholder="Password" value=""/> <br>
                <input type="password" name="confirmPassword" id="confirmPassword"placeholder="Confirm Password" value=""/> <br>
                <input type="text" name="phoneNumber" id="phoneNumber" placeholder="Phone Number" maxlength="10" value=""/> <br>
                <input type="date" name="birthday" id="birthday" placeholder="Birthday" value=""/> <br>
                <label id="legalConfirm" for="agree"><input type="hidden" name="agree" value="0" /><input type="checkbox" name="agree" id="agree" value="1" checked="checked" /> By clicking join you confirm that you accept our <a href="/privacy.html">Privacy Policy</a> and <a href="/terms.html">Terms of Service</a>.</label>
                <input class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" name="create" value="Join"/>
                <a href="/"><button type="button" class="btn">Cancel</button></a>
            </fieldset>
        </form>
```

Running the server.js file that connects to mongoose like this:

```
var express = require('express')
, home = require('./routes/home.js')
, path = require('path')
, http = require('http')
, bcrypt = require('bcrypt-nodejs')
, mongoose = require('mongoose');
mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/test');

var app = express();
app.get('/', home.index);
app.get('/signUp', home.signUp);
app.get('/about', home.about);
app.post('/signUp', home.signUpUser);
http.createServer(app).listen(app.get('port'), function(){
console.log('Express server listening on port ' + app.get('port'));
});
```

Then the router file

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var conn = mongoose.connection;
var bcrypt = require('bcrypt-nodejs');
var User = require('../models/user-model');
exports.signUpUser = function (req, res, next) {
if (req.body && req.body.email && req.body.password === req.body.confirmPassword) {
    var obj = new User ({
        firstName: req.body.firstName || 'na',
        lastName: req.body.lastName || 'na',
        email: req.body.email,
        password: req.body.password,
        phone: req.body.phoneNumber || '555-555-555',
        birthday: new Date(req.body.birthday) || new Date()
    });
console.log(conn.collection('users'));
    conn.collection('users').insert(obj, function (err) {
        if (!err) {
            res.redirect('/about.html');
        } else {
            next(err);
        }
    });
} else {
    next(new Error('Incorrect POST'));
}
};
```

Then the user model file

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose'),
Schema = mongoose.Schema,
bcrypt = require('bcrypt-nodejs'),
SALT_WORK_FACTOR = 10;
 // these values can be whatever you want - we're defaulting to a
// max of 5 attempts, resulting in a 2 hour lock
MAX_LOGIN_ATTEMPTS = 5,
LOCK_TIME = 2 * 60 * 60 * 1000;

var UserSchema = new Schema({
email: { type: String, required: true, lowercase:true, index: { unique: true } },
password: { type: String, required: true },
firstName: {type: String, required: true},
lastName: {type: String, required: true},
phone: {type: Number, required: true},
birthday: {type: Date, required: true},


loginAttempts: { type: Number, required: true, default: 0 },
lockUntil: { type: Number }

});

 UserSchema.virtual('isLocked').get(function() {
// check for a future lockUntil timestamp
return !!(this.lockUntil && this.lockUntil > Date.now());
});


//password hashing middleware

UserSchema.pre('save', function(next) {
var user = this;

// only hash the password if it has been modified (or is new)
if (!user.isModified('password')) return next();

// generate a salt
bcrypt.genSalt(SALT_WORK_FACTOR, function(err, salt) {
    if (err) return next(err);

    // hash the password along with our new salt
    bcrypt.hash(user.password, salt, function(err, hash) {
        if (err) return next(err);

        // override the cleartext password with the hashed one
        user.password = hash;
        next();
    });
});    
});
//password verification

UserSchema.methods.comparePassword = function(candidatePassword, cb) {
bcrypt.compare(candidatePassword, this.password, function(err, isMatch) {
    if (err) return cb(err);
    cb(null, isMatch);
});
};


UserSchema.methods.incLoginAttempts = function(cb) {
// if we have a previous lock that has expired, restart at 1
if (this.lockUntil && this.lockUntil < Date.now()) {
    return this.update({
        $set: { loginAttempts: 1 },
        $unset: { lockUntil: 1 }
    }, cb);
}
// otherwise we're incrementing
var updates = { $inc: { loginAttempts: 1 } };
// lock the account if we've reached max attempts and it's not locked already
if (this.loginAttempts + 1 >= MAX_LOGIN_ATTEMPTS && !this.isLocked) {
    updates.$set = { lockUntil: Date.now() + LOCK_TIME };
}
return this.update(updates, cb);
};

// expose enum on the model, and provide an internal convenience reference 
var reasons = UserSchema.statics.failedLogin = {
NOT_FOUND: 0,
PASSWORD_INCORRECT: 1,
MAX_ATTEMPTS: 2
};

UserSchema.statics.getAuthenticated = function(username, password, cb) {
this.findOne({ username: username }, function(err, user) {
    if (err) return cb(err);

    // make sure the user exists
    if (!user) {
        return cb(null, null, reasons.NOT_FOUND);
    }

    // check if the account is currently locked
    if (user.isLocked) {
        // just increment login attempts if account is already locked
        return user.incLoginAttempts(function(err) {
            if (err) return cb(err);
            return cb(null, null, reasons.MAX_ATTEMPTS);
        });
    }

    // test for a matching password
    user.comparePassword(password, function(err, isMatch) {
        if (err) return cb(err);

        // check if the password was a match
        if (isMatch) {
            // if there's no lock or failed attempts, just return the user
            if (!user.loginAttempts && !user.lockUntil) return cb(null, user);
            // reset attempts and lock info
            var updates = {
                $set: { loginAttempts: 0 },
                $unset: { lockUntil: 1 }
            };
            return user.update(updates, function(err) {
                if (err) return cb(err);
                return cb(null, user);
            });
        }

        // password is incorrect, so increment login attempts before responding
        user.incLoginAttempts(function(err) {
            if (err) return cb(err);
            return cb(null, null, reasons.PASSWORD_INCORRECT);
        });
    });
});
};

module.exports = mongoose.model('User', UserSchema);
```

Any problems that can lead to this? I am assuming it might be something is on my form/router file that is not included on the user-model file.

Also, if anyone notices if the security code is correct in terms of using Salt, hash/bcrypt, that would be great!

If it is correct what is it suppose to show in the db as for the password(null or some encrypted code?)

Comment: That error sounds like infinite recursion, but I don't see anything obvious.  Do you have a line number or a call stack?

Comment: The only thing I can think of is the fact that in the route file I have a new User object being called and in the user-model.js file on the bottom I have a UserSchema that calls emails and what not too... but I do not understand how to differentiate it... I tried removing the details in the route file (such as the email, password, birthday, etc..) but it still repeats the same error... trying to debug it with console.log but not getting anything that I can understand...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so I had a friend who has a little more knowledge than me look at it. First off I left out something because I was looking at an example with an older version of bcrypt so I had to add null to this line instead of progress

in the user-model.js file

bcrypt.hash(user.password, salt, null, function(err, hash)

in the router file I had insert instead of save and I was calling it on the mongoose connection which wasn't needed

obj.save(function(err)

Also removed these from the header, they were not needed

var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var conn = mongoose.connection;

The password does resule in a salt and hash as well.